# Maven - grab latest upload of artifact

Tags: maven, nexus

I am trying to install the latest uploaded version of an artifact into my local repository.

For example:

I have a pulsar artifact that was initially uploaded on 12/10. I have recently added to the pulsar artifact and the blob has the updated date 12/17

Blob created    Thu Dec 10 2020 10:57:13 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Blob updated    Thu Dec 17 2020 12:16:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

I would like to run a command that will grab the latest blobs for all artifacts in my maven repository in Nexus

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: For what purpose? Why not just run a Maven build and let Maven download the artifacts?

Comment: So we are downloading the artifacts to a local repository that get used for our builds. Every so often a developer will add a change to the artifact and use the same artifactID and version. I need to be able to grab the latest updated blob, otherwise I would need to delete the artifact from the local repository manually so that it can get redownloaded

Comment: But why don't you just build against the Nexus? Why do you need to copy artifacts from Nexus to a local repository? Maven automatically downloads the artifacts to the local repository. Furthermore, it also updates SNAPSHOT dependencies.

Comment: We use apache ant to build, otherwise we would include the dependencies in the build. We are pulling down the dependencies to a local repository that is a central repository used for multiple applications (IT doesn't give us a ton of space to have each build grab it's own set of dependencies). If the dependencies are already pulled down, we don't run a mvn install. We just build using the ant script

Comment: Ok, but then I would really try to switch from Ant to Maven as soon as possible. This will make your life much easier. And if you need to run some parts of your Ant scripts, you can do this in Maven as well.

Comment: Easier said than done! That may be the next step in our process. There's 25 years of development to unravel in order to convert ant to maven. Unless you have any suggestions of how to easily convert! :)

Comment: Most builds are not very hard to convert. Maven has a lot of things out of the box, and for many other things, there are Maven plugins. If you need something special in Ant, you can use the maven antrun plugin and run that script during the Maven build. I converted a large number of projects, and for most of them it is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Your local maven repository is throw-away. It's really just a cache of artifacts found in various remote repositories during previous builds.

If you have already built against version 1.0-SNAPSHOT of some artifact, Maven will find that artifact in your local repo, and not attempt to refresh it from the remote.

You can override this with the -U option (--update-snapshots). This will force Maven to re-download snapshot artifacts from your Nexus repo.

```
mvn -U clean install ...
```

HTH